# How to parse JSON API Link to HTML Table

Tags: json, api

I'm trying to parse an API json file to an HTML table, i posted the contents of the JSON API file in here for reference: https://pastebin.com/raw/jWaET2TU

For start i wanted to make it simple, just 3 values.

ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION

I can print all data, then when I try to fetch individual values or i get an error or a blank page.

This is all i have till now, but can't figure out what's wrong in the code.

.HTML

```
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<style>
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}   
</style>
```

.JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://apiexample.com',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.headline + "</td>"));
}
```